# Repetition of articles in a sentence

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, sentence-patterns, repetition

The following sentences use more than one adjective for a single noun.

> She has **a** black and white cat.

It implies that the person involved here has only one cat which is *black and white coloured*.

The following sentence is however different from the preceding one.

> She has **a** black and **a** white cat.

The indefinite article *a* has been repeated as many times as there are adjectives for the noun in the sentence changing in meaning of the sentence - the person involved has now two cats - one is a black coloured cat and the other is a white coloured cat.

---

Similarly, the following sentence implies designations.

> **The** magistrate and collector **is** present.

**One** person owns two different designations which are magistrate and collector.

The following sentence however implies two different persons - one is a magistrate and the other is a collector.

> **The** magistrate and **the** collector **are** present.

---

What do the following sentences mean?

> - He is **a** better counsellor than **a** scholar.
> - He is **a** better counsellor than scholar.

and

> - He is **a** better poet than **a** novelist.
> - He is **a** better poet than novelist.

Comment: You obviously know that the first of each of your pairs is potentially ambiguous! Hence context is important because context helps to resolve ambiguity. Without context, this fits the Not A Real Question closure criteria, which is a pity because the question is actually quite well-constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He is a better counsellor than a scholar.
>   He is a better poet than a novelist.

Both of these are ambiguous. They could mean he's a better counsellor (poet) than a scholar (novelist) is or that he's better at being a counsellor (poet) than at being at scholar (novelist).

The other two mean that he's better at doing the first than at doing the second.